# C program to print next five prime numbers

Tags: c, gcc

I have a program that prints five prime numbers within a user input range(m,n).

My problem is i want to print numbers greater than m. and print only next five numbers. I don't want to use upper limit.

How can I do it so?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
 int m,n,i,j,k,flag;


 printf("\nEnter The Lower Limit: ");
 scanf("%d",&m);
 printf("\nEnter The Upper Limit: ");
 scanf("%d",&n);

 printf("\nPrime Numbers Between %d & %d Are:\n",m,n);
 for(i=m ; i<=n ; i++)
 {
  k=i;
  flag=1;
  for(j=2 ; (j<=k/2)&&flag ; j++)
  {
   if(k%j==0)
   flag=0;
  }

  if(flag)
  printf("%3d \n",i);
 }


}
```

Comment: You need to show what **you** have tried. Yes, you *have* a program, but looks like it's taken from [here](http://www.codingbot.net/2013/07/generate-prime-numbers-within-range-of.html), so, not **your** code.

Comment: @YuHao; Good searching skill :)

Comment: @haccks Haha, the words *I have a program* instead of *I wrote a program* makes me wonder. The searching is done using one unique statement to google (I used the third `printf` line)

Comment: I am impressed. +1 @YuHao. Didn't think of putting an actual line of code with meaningful string in google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply count the number of primes you have printed?

> ```
> int count = 0;
>
> :
>
> for(i=m ; (i<=n) && (count<5) ; i++)
>
> :
>
> if(flag)
> {
>   printf("%3d \n",i);
>   count++;
> }
> ```

PS, using longer names than single characters will help make your program more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you like it or not, you have a higher limit which is set by the data type you use -> **int**, in your case.  Imagine you want the first 5 prime numbers larger than (MAXINT- 10)...you get the point, but let's assume you are not concerned about corner-cases.

```
int count=0;
int i=m;
int k;
while (count<5)
{
  k=i;
  flag=1;
  for(j=2 ; (j<=k/2)&&flag ; j++)
  {
   if(k%j==0)
   flag=0;
  }

  if(flag)
  {
     printf("%3d \n",i);
     count++;
  }

  i++;
}
```